# Importing XML Data into Google Sheets from a Web-based Source

Tags: xml, xpath, amazon-s3, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to build a Google Sheet that pulls information from the IRS Form 990 repository hosted via AWS S3.

Here is the XML file: [Example 990 Form in XML](https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201702299349300445_public.xml)

The query I'm doing is designed to pull the business names under the Schedule I section from the XML source. The business name is wrapped in the `BusinessNameLine1Txt`tags.

Utilizing the built-in `IMPORTXML` function from Google Sheet I've built the following:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201702299349300445_public.xml", "//Return/ReturnData/IRS990ScheduleI/RecipientTable/RecipientBusinessName/BusinessNameLine1Txt")
```

When I execute the function with parameters seen above I receive an error saying that the imported content is empty. Is my XPATH query incorrect or does it have to do with some quirk in the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification?

```
=IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[local-name()='BusinessNameLine1Txt']")
```

- `https://s3.amazonaws.com/irs-form-990/201702299349300445_public.xml` is put in "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [local-name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name)

If I misunderstand your issue, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Edit:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[local-name()='IRS990ScheduleI']//*[local-name()='BusinessNameLine1Txt']")
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, that was helpful. Do you know how to specify so that query just   selects the business names from the Schedule I section?

Comment: @Matt I'm really sorry for my incomplete answer. The values you want is ``=IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[local-name()='IRS990ScheduleI']//*[local-name()='BusinessNameLine1Txt']")``? If I misunderstand again, please tell me.

Comment: thank you this is exactly what I was looking for! Would you happen to know why I couldn't use the syntax I wrote in the original question.

Comment: @Matt At first, I tried ``=IMPORTXML(A1, "/Return")``. If the data has not issues, the some values are returned. But ``#N/A`` was returned. So I checked the XML data. It was found that when ``http://www.irs.gov/efile`` of ``xmlns="http://www.irs.gov/efile"`` in ``Return`` is removed (for example, it's ``xmlns=""``.), your xpath worked fine. But the existing XML cannot be modified. So I proposed to use ``local-name()``. If this was not useful, I'm sorry.